# Debian 10: My network interface name changed from enp7s0 to enp6s0

Tags: debian, networking

My understanding is that the network name in the format "enpXsY" is supposed to be a persistent interface name, however between reboots my interface name changed from `enp7s0` to `enp6s0`.

Are there any possible reasons for this?

It resulted in my `nfs` not being mountable, as the server did not raise the nfs network interface on boot.

I cannot change the ip assignment to dynamic and use a dhcp server to set this network address as it is a direct link between two computers.

Answer (score 1):

If the name changed, that also means the PCI ID of the NIC changed from 7:0.0 to 6:0.0.

Did you make any changes to hardware configuration or BIOS settings?

Comment: No, I don't believe so, although I removed some USB devices. Could that change something?